# Can I initialise the vue root instance with a .vue class component?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I am using `vue-class-component` so that I can use class syntax and typescript type checking in `.vue` files. I can create .vue files and register them as components with this syntax, except for the root Vue() instance.

**This works**

The `hello.vue` file looks like this, it's using `vue-class-component` (shortened for brevity)

```
<template></template>

<script lang="ts">
    import Vue from 'vue'
    import Component from 'vue-class-component'
    @Component({
    })
    export default class Hello extends Vue {
        created() {
            console.log("I am created!")
        }
    }
</script>
```

Now, I can import hello in the root vue instance like this:

```
import Hello from "./components/hello.vue"

let v = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    template: `<div><hello></hello></div>`,
    components: {Hello},
    created : function(){
        console.log("root instance created")
    }
});
```

**This doesn't work**

I'd like to be able to use the same class syntax when creating the root vue instance:

app.vue

```
<template><hello></hello></template>

<script lang="ts">
    import Vue from 'vue'
    import Component from 'vue-class-component'
    import Hello from "./components/hello.vue"

    @Component({
        el: "#app",
        components: {Hello}
    })

    export default class App extends Vue {
        created() {
            console.log("created the root instance")
        }
    }
</script>
```

And then import app.vue in index.ts.

```
import Vue from "vue"
import App from "./components/app.vue"

let vm = new Vue(App)
```

Trying to use `App` to initialise the vue root instance gives this error:

```
Argument of type 'typeof Vue' is not assignable to parameter 
of type 'ComponentOptions<Vue> | undefined'
```

How can I define a ComponentOptions? And would it be possible that the entry point of the app is a .vue file instead of index.ts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `components` section of an options object can specify components by spec or (apparently, I can't find this in the documentation) by including the component itself.

The `Vue` constructor does not accept a component, it requires a spec. Since a component is already an extension of `Vue`, so there's no reason to try to run it back through the `Vue` constructor. Just say

```
let vm = new App();
```

From the comments, it also turns out that specifying `el` should be left to the constructor call and not be included in the `@Component`, so it should be

```
let vm = new App({el: '#app'});
```

Comment: Perhaps my phrasing was unclear, but the code above works for components (it uses `vue-class-component` to enable class syntax). My problem is that this syntax does not work for the root Vue instance.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show exactly what works and what doesn't?

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: That seems to make sense, but I get: `option "el" can only be used during instance creation with the new keyword`

Comment: I'm not clear on how the `@Component` figures into this. I haven't used `vue-class-component` myself. Possibly if you left the `el` spec out of `@Component` and passed it to the constructor: `new App({el : '#app'})`

Comment: I'm following the instructions on https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html , but hey, your solution actually works! I can also type it out completely by using `let opt:ComponentOptions<Vue> = {el : '#app'}; let vm = new App(opt)`